# Which bem unit to use for 'left' - 'right' - 'bottom' - 'top' properties?

Tags: html, css, bem

I am stucking with placing `left` and `top` property to CSS according to BEM methodology.
My structure is

```
<body class="page-content">
    <div class="page-content__calculator-container page-content__calculator-container_shift_left calculator-container">
        <div class="calculator_container__button calculator_container__button-close"></div>
        <div class="calculator-container __content calculator-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<style>
    .page-content__calculator-container {
        position: fixed;
        top: 5vh;
        left: 3vw;
    }

    .page-content__calculator-container_shift_left {
        left: -3vw;
    }
```

With js logic in some cases I will add `page-content__calculator-container_shift_left` class for reposition element.

In BEM documentation

> In CSS with BEM, styles that are responsible for the external geometry
>   and positioning are set via the parent block.

Bem suggests using `page-content__calculator-container` - for positioning.
But If I want to reposition this element with js class do I need to replace current block element with 
`page-content__calculator-container-repositioned` Or do I need add modifier 
`page-content__calculator-container_shift_left` - and then use `left` and `top` CSS properties inside modifier CSS? But modifier don't need to be used for positioning. If I use modifier then my `top` and `left` properties will be simultaneously in `page-content__calculator-container` and in `page-content__calculator-container_shift_left`.

What to use in this case? Maybe Am I thinking wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on semantics of your project.

But common answer is that you don't need to replace initial entity with `page-content__calculator-container-repositioned`. Feel free to add modifiers but pay attention to the order of them in your CSS: `_shift_*` modifiers should have priority so they could always override styling of `page-content__calculator-container`.